# Which functions trigger which authorizations for an apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, authorization

When apps scripts run as the user, the user must authorize them to do certain things, depending on the functions used in the script. In the simplest case, there is no authorization, but if you use a function in the script like `Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()`, the authorization is something like: this app will "View your email address" and this app "Will know who you are on Google". If you access a spreadsheet in the script, it will say something like: this app needs permission to "View and manage your spreadsheets in Google Drive".

1) Is there any explanation of what those permissions really mean in detail? I believe the last one means "spreadsheets that are shared with the app...." and not all the user's spreadsheets! I want to be able to point the app user to Google's explanation, but I haven't found a link.

2) Which script functions will trigger a new permission? I know it seems pretty obvious, but I have one app that does not access a spreadsheet and yet I am getting "View and manage your spreadsheets in Google Drive" request. I could be that is because one of the earlier version of that app does access spreadsheets. Not sure!

Thanks!

PS: some discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12340955/clarification-on-active-user-scope-and-script-authorization), but not quite what I want.

Answer (score 0):

For question number 2, make sure that you've gone into your script's project properties and select "manage versions" to make sure that you have an updated version, and then go back to publish and change the published version to the most current version (that doesn't access the spreadsheet anymore).

Comment: I think I found one stumbling block: even functions in code that is commented out and will never be run will trigger the authorization. I deleted the comments, and then it elicited the expected authorization. Since I undid the authorization, when I use the "latest version" I get the authorization prompt and can see what will be required of the user...

Comment: So deleting out the commented section clears the request for auth on the spreadsheet?  Makes sense, because it would probably be better for security to authorize anything that is possible within the content of the code, so it wouldn't trigger a re-auth of you uncommented the code after deployment.

Comment: Yes, or perhaps I simply got a re-auth after cutting out comments. But in some sense it is odd because really the comments don't count and should not trigger authorization -- more experimenting needed!